# Really slow editing long org-mode blocks

Tags: org-mode, text-editing, performance

When editing inside a long org-mode block (`#+BEGIN_....` - `#+END_....`) Emacs is really slow (it can take several seconds to write a single character), while editing the rest of the buffer takes normal time.
I found this ([org-mode 9 too slow with long code blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46561/org-mode-9-too-slow-with-long-code-blocks)) which is related to source blocks (whilst my problem is with "custom" blocks: #+BEGIN_exercise, #+BEGIN_solution, #+BEGIN_theorem,... which have no direct meaning in org) and found that also in this type of blocks the problem is the syntax highlighting:

```
M-x profiler-start   
Type a character in the code block
M-x profiler-report
```

```
- redisplay_internal (C function)                                                              1498  68%
 - jit-lock-function                                                                           1492  67%
  - jit-lock-fontify-now                                                                       1492  67%
   - jit-lock--run-functions                                                                   1492  67%
    - run-hook-wrapped                                                                         1492  67%
     + #<compiled 0x155edb4743f1>                                                              1492  67%
```

But inside these blocks I write common org syntax, so it's not needed to call jit-lock to highlight it: is there a way to enable it only for source blocks?

Maybe if exporting an heading as a block could be possible ([Is it possible in org-mode to export a * heading to a \begin{heading} \end{heading} block construct?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16483/is-it-possible-in-org-mode-to-export-a-heading-to-a-beginheading-endheadi)) it can be a solution.